# Desparece la ultima columna cuando se utilicé xticks de matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualización-de-datos

Tengo un cojunto de datos `low_dimensional_split`:

```
    grade   int_rate    installment dti revol_bal   revol_util  inq_last_6mths  delinq_2yrs pub_rec acc_open_past_24mths
0   C   12.69   469.63  17.07   5848    90.0    1.0 0.0 0.0 4.0
1   B   9.17    31.88   12.51   7634    37.2    3.0 0.0 1.0 4.0
2   A   6.89    400.75  21.72   11113   24.4    0.0 0.0 0.0 10.0
3   A   6.24    170.98  2.45    3402    41.5    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   C   12.29   246.31  24.35   6062    68.9    1.0 2.0 0.0 3.0
```

Quiero hacer su gráfico de correlación

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(19, 15))
plt.matshow(low_dimensional_split.corr(), fignum=f.number)
plt.xticks(range(low_dimensional_split.shape[1]), low_dimensional_split.columns, fontsize=14, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(range(low_dimensional_split.shape[1]), low_dimensional_split.columns, fontsize=14)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
plt.title('Correlation Matrix', fontsize=16);
```

Pero cuando al utilsar plt.xticks desparece la ultima columna. Se pasa lo mismo con las lineas :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que por un lado `range(low_dimensional_split.shape[1])` es un range(0,10) y  `low_dimensional_split.columns` tiene 10 columnas, y por el otro al haber hecho `.corr()` en `.matshow` la columna `grade` desaparece por tener valores tipo texto, quedandote 9 datos.

Es decir, estás pasandole 10 ticks y 10 etiquetas pero solamente 9 datos, tanto en el eje X como en el Y.

Para sustituirlo rápido y ver que funciona cambia el numero de ticks poniendo:

```
range(low_dimensional_split.shape[1] - 1)
```

Con esto te saldrá:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De todas formas, en esa imagen te aparecería la etiqueta `grade`, que no debería puesto que no está en los datos que estás comparando. Por lo que lo correcto sería:

```
lds = low_dimensional_split.corr()

f = plt.figure(figsize=(19, 15))
plt.matshow(lds, fignum=f.number)
plt.xticks(range(lds.shape[1]), lds, fontsize=14, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(range(lds.shape[1]), lds, fontsize=14)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
plt.title('Correlation Matrix', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Que ahora si que da tiene sentido (he girado las etiquetas del eje x a 90º para que veas que salen bien posicionadas que con 45º no lo parece).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]